# What tool can I use to vertically merge two or more screenshots?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

I want to merge two or more images (screenshots from mobile phones) easy and fast. The purpose is to obtain a long image, similar to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPwtV.gif).

What software can I use? I know I can do this in Adobe Photoshop but it's time consuming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might not be as time-consuming using Photoshop as you think. You can somewhat automate this using the built-in Photomerge tool. For demonstration purposes, I've created a conversation that totally didn't happen using [fakephonetext.com](http://www.fakephonetext.com).

[image: fake text conversation]

You should first crop out the bits of UI that are repeated in each image, so going along with the example all of the images should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1YT0.png). Save each image as a separate file.

Then use <kbd>File > Automate > Photomerge...</kbd> and select **Auto** for the Layout and Browse for your source files. Hit OK and the magic should work as long as there's enough overlap in each image for Photoshop to detect.

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIOr4.png), you can add the UI bits back in if needed. If you'd like to give this a spin with my cropped example images, you can download them here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1YT0.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA7Qx.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI0bN.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJM6W.png).

Comment: *cough, cough -- **nothing** is scott-free. Just like I tell my clients.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective tools on the web seem to be these two:

[PhotoJoiner](http://www.photojoiner.net/)

Advantages: free, easy to use, fast, lightweight.

Downsides: not very accurate (if you want to overlay sections of images, you can't do it).

[QuickPictureTool](http://www.quickpicturetools.com/en/combine_images/)

Advantages: free, accurate, effective.

Downsides: not easy to use, not very user friendly, maximum image height is 2000px.

On your case I would recommend the second one since you already have some experience with PS I think you will find QuickPictureTool easy to master.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's more easier for me do to how JohnB said. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by command line using the `-tile` option of the `montage` command from **ImageMagick**. See [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#tile) for details and examples.